# I have 1 VB 2017 Project (out of several) with no SUO files. How do I get the options file back?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, suo

I have several vb 2017 projects. Just 1 is missing the SUO file and so none of the options, i.e. open files, breakpoints, watch lists, etc. are saved.

The other projects work just fine.

How I do I get this one VB project to get this SUO working again?

Thanks

Comment: it is problably hidden only and when you really delete it you can reset all https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299660/vs-corrupted-sln-file

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out.

The SLN project name ended with underscores i.e. Project____.SLN.

Once I removed the _ it created the SUO and now it remembers the open files, etc.